# How do you explicitly specify a namespace when using "apply" on a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Here "graph" is higher-order function that returns a function with config set in its scope:

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.graph)

(defn out1
  "Test func that simply returns out1."
  [config]
  "out1")

(defn graph
  [config]
  (fn [func & args]
    (apply func config args)))
```

You create an instance of graph, which can then be used to call other functions and automatically pass in the config arg:

```
(def g (graph {:root-uri "http://localhost"}))

(g out1)
;; => "out1"
```

This works; however, if you require/import graph into another namespace, then you have  to prefix each function call with the graph namespace:

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.junk
  (:require [bulbs.neo4jserver.graph :as graph]))

(def g (graph/graph {:root-uri "http://localhost"}))

;; would rather do (g out1)
(g graph/out1)
```

Instead, I want to explicitly specify the namespace in the `apply` function so that users don't have to:

```
(defn graph
  [config]
  (fn [func & args]
    ;; somehow specify the graph namespace here
    (apply func config args)))
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Using `graph/out1` is explicit and much more clean/simpler thing to do rather that doing some magic, because if you do that then it would be a high order function at all

Comment: What if you want to use a custom function, instead of out1 (or anything else in the bulbs.neo4jserver.graph namespace)? Prefixing a symbol unnecessarily restricts the flexibility and extensibility of your library. I agree with Ankur: don't do it, it's much cleaner and more idiomatic without the magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass symbol instead of function and resolve it in `graph` function:

```
(defn graph
  [config]
  (fn [func & args]
    (apply (ns-resolve 'bulbs.neo4jserver.graph func) config args)))
```

And call it:

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.junk
  (:require [bulbs.neo4jserver.graph :as graph]))

(def g (graph/graph {:root-uri "http://localhost"}))

(g 'out1)
```

But `g` is not an high-order function any more. It takes symbol, not function. Personally I don't like this approach. Why don't you like specifying namespace? May be you can do what you need with macro too, but I don't know macros well.

**EDIT**

Don't do it. Use regular functions as explained by @Ankur and @Gert in comments.

Comment: Thanks Nikita. I'm porting a Python library (http://bulbflow.com) to Clojure and am trying to keep the interfaces as close as possible: g.vertices.create(name="James") ideally would be (g vertices/create {:name "James"}), without having to require that users import all the namespaces for the graph -- here the "vertices" namespace would have been imported in the graph.clj and all the user has to do is import the "graph" namespace -- this makes it easy to use from the REPL.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but the general pattern you're using is more common: having a single stateful data structure that holds connection parameters (to a database or another server). Most frameworks turn this around: instead of calling your functions from within the function holding your connection parameters as you do, they have functions that accept the connection data structure as a parameter.

For example, given a database connetion `conn`, a typical, fictional database library could look like this (note: examples are simplified for clarity):

```
(let [conn (make-db-connection :host .... :user ....)]
  (read-from-db conn :user))
```

While using a library for a messaging framework (say, RabbitMQ) could look like this:

```
(let [conn (make-amqp-connection :host .... :port ...)]
  (send-message conn :my-queue "hello world"))
```

In both situations, there is a single `conn` data structure that is used for all subsequent calls to the libraries' functions. In OO languages, you would have a global, stateful object holding the connection (a singleton perhaps in Java land). In Clojure, libraries typically handle this using a `with-...` macro, that binds a particular connection to a dynamic var which is used internally:

```
(with-db-connection (make-db-connection ....)
  (read-from-db :user ....))

(with-rabbit-connection (make-rabbitmq-connection ....)
  (send-message :my-queue "hello world"))
```

Here's a (fictional) example that implements this pattern. Assume that a connection is a Java object:

```
;; a var to hold the connection
(def ^:dynamic *current-connection* nil)


(defmacro with-connection [conn & body]
  `(binding [*current-connection* ~conn]
     ~@body))

;; send-msg is using the connection object bound to
;; the *current-connetion* var
(defn send-msg [msg]
  (.sendMessage *current-connection* msg))

;; usage:
(with-connection conn
  (send-msg "hello world!"))
```

If you want to be fancy, you could support both patterns (accepting a connection as a parameter *or* using the bound connection) by defining the `send-msg` function like this:

```
(defn send-msg [msg & {:keys [connection]
                       :or {connection *current-connection*}}]
  (.sendMessage connection msg))

;; usage with bound connetion:
(with-connection conn
  (send-msg "Hello World!"))

;; usage with explicit connection:
(send-msg "Hello World!"
          :connection conn)
```

This version of `send-msg` uses the supplied connection, *or* the bound connection if a connection wasn't specified.