# Is there a performance penalty when calling a function using ns-resolve in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

This works, but I'm curious what the performance penalty is for dynamically passing in a namespace and resolving it using ns-resolve...

```
(ns bulbs.vertices)

(defn create
  [config data]
  ((ns-resolve (:ns config) 'create-vertex) config data))
```

And then call it like this...

```
(ns bulbs.neo4jserver.graph
  (:require [bulbs.vertices :as vertices])
  (:require [bulbs.neo4jserver.client :as client]))

(defn graph
  [& [config]]
  (let [config (client/build-config config {:ns 'bulbs.neo4jserver.client})]
    (fn [func & args]
      (apply func config args))))

(def g (graph))

(g vertices/create {:name "James"})
```

Comment: If you need to check at runtime which function to bind to a name, why don't you use `(alter-var-root ...)` after you've determined that? Then you would be able to use the function the normal way. Another approach is to dynamically decide which file to load that will define functions for a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unless your `ns-resolve` is part of a loop (and unless you need to dynamically resolve a different function in every iteration there is absolutely no need for this), I wouldn't worry about a performance penalty.

But yes, there is a performance penalty:

```
user=> (time (dotimes [n 1000000] (let [f (ns-resolve 'clojure.core 'inc)] (f n))))
"Elapsed time: 175.386 msecs"
nil
user=> (time (dotimes [n 1000000] (let [f inc] (f n))))
"Elapsed time: 27.022 msecs"
nil
```

If you really really *really* need the `ns-resolve` magic (but see the replies to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572443/how-do-you-explicitly-specify-a-namespace-when-using-apply-on-a-function-in-cl) discouraging you from doing this in your particular situation), and if the function you're resolving is used in a loop, take the resolve out of that loop:

```
user=> (time (let [f (ns-resolve 'clojure.core 'inc)] (dotimes [n 1000000] (f n))))
"Elapsed time: 48.538 msecs"
nil
```

Comment: Hi Gert - I think you mean this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572443/how-do-you-explicitly-specify-a-namespace-when-using-apply-on-a-function-in-cl . But notice I didn't put `ns-resolve` in the graph function -- I moved it to the lower-level `vertices` functions so that you can pass in a custom function to `graph` if desired. If the `ns-resolve` magic is less than desirable. what's a better way to avoid code duplication -to avoid writing separate functions for every backend database the client supports. I haven't gone the protocol route because they don't support varargs

Comment: +1 for the good analysis. Though the overhead looks like only 150ns or so per iteration to me - so even if this is in a loop, I doubt it would be a big issue!

Comment: Evidently one of the underlying libraries, clj-http, uses (ns-resolve) as well in its json-encode/decode functions (http://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/client.clj), which is used on every request.